# Haskell - how to count elements in nested list

Tags: list, haskell, overloading, counting

Lets say I have nested lsit: [1, [2, 3, 4], [5, [6]]] and I want to count how many elements it has. In this case it is six elements. I have written such code for doing this:

```
totalElems :: [a] -> Int
totalElems (x:xs) = case (x, xs) of
                    (_, []) -> 0
                    (y:ys, _) -> 1 + totalElems ys + totalElems xs
                    (_, _) -> 1 + totalElems xs
```

But I've got an error:

```
a.hs:4:42:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for totalElems :: [a] -> Int at a.hs:1:15
    Relevant bindings include
      xs :: [a] (bound at a.hs:2:15)
      x :: a (bound at a.hs:2:13)
      totalElems :: [a] -> Int (bound at a.hs:2:1)
    In the pattern: y : ys
    In the pattern: (y : ys, _)
    In a case alternative:
        (y : ys, _) -> 1 + totalElems ys + totalElems xs
```

How I can do this in Haskell?

Comment: Every element of a list must be the same type.  If you want some other structure, you don't want a list.

Comment: We call those structures *tree*s in haskell.

Answer (score 7):

You can't make freeform lists-within-lists like that in Haskell.  Dynamically typed langues will tolerate silliness like that, but strongly-typed Haskell won't.

`1` is of type `Int`, and `[2,3,4]` is of a different type `[Int]`.  Things in a list have to be of the same type.

However, you could do something like this:

```
data Nest a = Elem a | List [Nest a]

example ::Nest Int
example = List [Elem 1, List [Elem 2, Elem 3, Elem 4], List [Elem 5, List [Elem 6]]]

countNest :: Nest a -> Int
countNest (Elem x) = 1
countNest (List xs) = sum $ map countNest xs
```

Comment: Your `countNest` function doesn't count the elements but sums their value.

Comment: Yes, I slightly misread the question.  It actually counts now.

Comment: re "silliness": in a dynamic environment it's just the equivalent of a sum type — why is that silly?

Comment: @ErikAllik Sum types are not silly.  Keeping your baby food, rat poison, floor wax, and dessert toppings in the same jar is silly.

Comment: I know what you mean but in a dynamically typed language, the "plain" representation is as good as using "separate jars" — in one way or another you'll end up branching based on the type of the item, regardless of whether it's an actual type check or just a boolean attribute. And it's just as easy to forget the check with or without an additional layer of jars. Or, in other words: `[1, [2, 3]]` is just as fool proof or error prone as is `[Left(1), Right([2, 3])]` in a language such as, say, Python. Furthermore, they are semantically isomorphic/equivalent because dynamic languages have RTTI.

Comment: Alternatively: you could say the runtime types _are_ the jar.

Comment: @ErikAllik No, there's a tremendous difference between a program proven by the compiler to type check and a program that has to repeatedly check the type of every argument at every calculation at run time.

Comment: so basically we've descended into an argument about dynamic vs static, which was something I didn't say anything about, so let's not continue it.

Answer (score 4):

> Let's say I have nested lsit: [1, [2, 3, 4], [5, [6]]]

You can't have that list. It won't type-check. Try typing it by itself in GHCi; it'll just spit an error message at you. Since this input can't exist in the first place, trying to write a function to process it is a doomed endeavor.

Instead, you need to define a custom data type for this. See the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the simplest way to do this is with a different data structure, like the [tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31236394/589352) NovaDenizen defined. However, just so you know, Haskell's type system enables various ways of creating "lists" in which the elements have different types : see https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections